# How to Get Parent Term from child term using TaxCatchAll?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, term-store, term-set, term

Suppose a SharePoint list has managed metadata column "A". List contains the item with the child term tagged to that "A" column.

Now when I try to fetch the term using rest API like this:

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle("ListName")/items/?$select=*,TaxCatchAll/Id,TaxCatchAll/Term&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

It gives me Id and Child Term Name, but I want to fetch the Parent Term also. How to achieve this?